# Passing IP in string to htonl

Tags: c, sockets, kernel-module

I am binding to socket in a kernel module. I get the IP in string format from another socket. How should I pass this IP to htonl(). I tried typecasting it to (long int). But, obviously it won't work.

How to achieve this?

Comment: you could use `inet_addr()`

Comment: so it should be addr_send.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unsigned int inet_addr(char *str)
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    char arr[4];
    sscanf(str, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    arr[0] = a; arr[1] = b; arr[2] = c; arr[3] = d;
    return *(unsigned int *)arr;
}

//use it as follows:
//inet_addr() returns address in Network Byte Order, so no need of htonl()

thesockaddr_in.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(str);
```

Comment: what is header file in kernel module?

Comment: @mahesh have updated the ans. write your own inet_addr

Comment: I've used that it returns 16777343 for 127.0.0.1. :(

Answer (score 3):

Yo can use something like this:

```
const char *IP = "62.4.36.125";
SOCKADDR_IN DestAddr;

DestAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
DestAddr.sin_port = htons (PORTNUM);
DestAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [**Beej's Guide to Network Programming**](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html#inet_ntoaman)

> inet_addr() returns the address as an in_addr_t, or -1 if there's an error. (That is the same result as if you tried to convert the string "255.255.255.255", which is a valid IP address. This is why inet_aton() is better.)

Example:

```
struct sockaddr_in antelope;
char *some_addr;

inet_aton("10.0.0.1", &antelope.sin_addr); // store IP in antelope

some_addr = inet_ntoa(antelope.sin_addr); // return the IP
printf("%s\n", some_addr); // prints "10.0.0.1"

// and this call is the same as the inet_aton() call, above:
antelope.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.1");
```